# Distinguishing between HFS+ and HFS Standard Volumes

Tags: macos, iokit, diskarbitration

IOKit and the DiskArbitration framework can tell me a lot of things about mounted volumes on a mac, but they don't seem to be able to differentiate between HFS+ and HFS Standard volumes.

The IOKit/DA keys `Content`, `DAVolumeKind` and `DAMediaContent` are always Apple_HFS and hfs for both HFS Standard and HFS+ volumes.

diskutil and DiskUtility.app *can* tell the difference, but I they don't seem to have been open sourced by Apple.

p.s. statfs (2) does not differentiate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use `getattrlist()` to retrieve the `ATTR_VOL_SIGNATURE` attribute for the mount path of the volume.
2. Use the Carbon call FSGetVolumeInfo() and look in the `signature` field of the returned struct.

The signature of a volume is a 16 bit value, usually interpreted as two ASCII characters.  The signature for HFS is 'BD', HFS+ is 'H+', and case sensitive HFS+ is 'HX'.

The man page for `getattrlist` says the field is a u_int32, but the equivalent field in the FSVolumeInfo struct is only 16 bits, so I'm not sure which 16 bits of the 32 are filled in with the signature when using `getattrlist`, you'll probably have to just experiment a bit if you want to go the non-Carbon route.

[getattrlist man page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getattrlist.2.html)

[HFS Plus Volume Format reference](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn1150.html)

[FSGetVolumeInfo](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSGetVolumeInfo)

Comment: I went with getattrlist because I didn't feel like linking in carbon, and can report the following: the lower 16 bits are filled in and HFS Standard -> BD, HFS+ -> H+ BUT, surprisingly, ntfs,fat32 -> BD and HFSX -> H+ (not HX). Weird, huh? Still, covers my case. Thanks.

Comment: In the FSVolumeInfo struct there is also a 16bit filesystemID whose value is 0 for HFS+ and 18771 for DOS FAT. I am still looking for something like an enum in a header file which would give all relevant values.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Carbon `FSGetVolumeInfo()` which returns a `FSVolumeInfo` containing `signature` and `filesystemID` fields, there is the Cocoa `-getFileSystemInfoForPath:` method of class `NSWorkspace` which returns a string representation of filesystem type: e.g., `hfs` for HFS+ and `msdos` for DOS FAT.

Answer (score 0):

The other problem you can run into should you ever try your hand at reading partition maps directly is that, historically, HFS+ volumes were nested inside HFS wrappers. This was done so that anyone trying to use an HFS+ disk with an older OS would see a single file on the drive explaining where all the rest of their data was.